# Какой HTTP код выдавать при попытке зарегестрироватся на занятый email?

Tags: http, response

Работаю над проектом и при создании пользователя проходит проверка на занятость email'а. Тот, кто изначально делал ответы на запросы сделал, что в случае занятого email'а отправляется код `400` через `throw new BadGatewayException`, я очень сомневаюсь что это правильно. Но сам не знаю какой код должен отправлятся в таком случае

Comment: 422 можно спокойно. Мы такой код отдаём вообще на непройденную валидацию